# Store the query results with multiple rows into csv and taking table name from user

Tags: sh, psql, greenplum

I am trying to store a Greenplum query result into a csv but it is storing only one row. I want to store multiple rows. Can anyone help with this.
I tried the below already but it is storing only one row.

```
r= `psql -A -t -q  -h $hostname -U $username  -d $dbname <<-THE_END
COPY(select * From ${gschema}.${gtable} order by ${key} limit 3) TO STDOUT with NULL as ' ' 
THE_END` > /home/gp.csv
```

I also tried below which is storing the result but I am unable to pass table name as parameter in the below query. For standard table names the output is as desired.

```
psql -h $hostname -U $username  -d $dbname -c "COPY (select * from table_name order by key limit 3) TO STDOUT "> /home/gp.csv
```

Can anyone help me with this please.
please note that I am trying to embed the above in a shell script

Comment: this is more of a bash question than a Greenplum question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
psql -A -t -q -h $hostname -U $username -d $dbname -c "select * from $gschema.$gtable order by $key limit 3" > /home/gp.csv
```

You could also put the SQL in a file:

example.sql

```
select * from :gschema.:gtable order by :key limit 3
```

And then to use the sql file:

```
psql -A -t -q -h $hostname -U $username -d $dbname -f example.sql -v gschema=public -v gtable=customer -v key=id > /home/gp.csv
```

Comment: This works.. Thank you so much for the help.. I will also keep the sql reference.